# How to grab the number?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, networking

writing a small script to perform house keeping tasks on my servers.

I want to grab just the X in ethX,

```
echo `grep -m1 -oE "eth[0-9]*" /etc/network/interfaces | grep -oE [0-9]*`
```

this works, but I was wondering if someone knew a one time command that can do it, ie a regular experession that can take a word for instance, room456 and only spit out the number.

Comment: echoing anything in backticks is redundant.  Just remove the echo and the backticks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [positive lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to match any digit string that is preceded by `eth`:

```
$ cat file
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
eth1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500

$ grep -Po '(?<=eth)[0-9]+' file
0
1
```

Comment: That's [positive lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) see the important notes for where it's supported (like `perl` hence the `-P` option as it's not supported by ER).

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`:

```
sed 's/^eth\([0-9]\+\):.*$/\1/g' /etc/network/interfaces
```